# How to change the type of a tuple?

Tags: rust, types, type-conversion

How can I convert`(u8, u8)` to `(usize, usize)` so I can compare the tuples like this `(u8, u8) == (usize, usize)`?

Comment: It would help to show an example of what you were trying to do. Have you tried recreating the tuple?

Comment: If your tuples are `a` and `b`, you can always use `(a.0 as usize, a.1 as usize) == b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `u8` is **not** `PartialEq<usize>`, `usize` is **not** `PartialEq<u8>`,  and Rust has no implicit conversion between primitive types by design, you need to convert both tuples to the same type to make them `PartialEq`.

##### Explicit conversion

as suggested by **user4815162342**

`usize` cannot be less than `u8`, so it is safe to make the explicit coercion
`u8` -> `usize`

```rust
(x.0 as usize, x.1 as usize) == y
```

But the coercion `usize` -> `u8` will truncate **silently**. The following snippet will compile and claim that x is equal to y.

```rust
let x: (u8, u8) = (255, 255);
let y: (usize, usize) = (1000, 1000);

    

 if (y.0 as u8, y.0 as u8) == x {
    println!("x and y are equal");
 } else {
    println!("x and y are not equal");
 }
```

##### `From` trait conversion

You can also do the conversion `u8` -> `usize` with `from`, since `usize` is `From<u8>`

```rust
(usize::from(x.0), usize::from(x.1)) == y
```

Note that `usize` -> `u8` with `from` doesn't compile since `u8` is not `From<usize>`.

```rust
(u8::from(y.0), u8::from(y.1)) == x
```

This why it is considered as a safe conversion method. Clippy can detect place where such conversions are possible with the rule [`cast_lossless` rule](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/)

##### `Try_From` trait conversion

You can also make a faillible conversion from `usize` to `u8` using `Try_From` trait.

```rust
match (u8::try_from(y.0), u8::try_from(y.1)) {
        (Ok(y_0), Ok(y_1)) => {
            if (y_0, y_1) == x {
                println!("x and y are equal");
            } else {
                println!("x and y are not equal");
            }
        },
        _ => panic!("Conversion from x type to y type failed")
}
```

The conversion will result in `Error` if `usize` value is greater than `u8::Max`. This also can be considered as a safe conversion method.